# Contacts in new look Gmail 2018

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, google-workspace-for-business

I've turned on the [new Gmail](https://www.blog.google/products/gmail/stay-composed-heres-quick-rundown-new-gmail/), and now notice that my Contacts button has disappeared. It used to be above Compose. Does anyone know where it has gone to?

Comment: Do you mean the button that just opens the contacts page/site?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I know how to get to the page as described but I thought I was going blind and missing the link from Gmail.  I believe contacts are getting a big overhaul, I guess this is somehow linked to that.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

1. Click 9 dots top right (Google apps)
2. If you don't see "Contacts", click "More"
3. You can change the place of "Contants" on this dropdown by draging the icon

[image]

Comment: Or just go to https://contacts.google.com

Answer (score 2):

Google decided to remove the contacts link because not many users used it. However, as others said, you can just click on the 9 dots or just go to [contacts.google.com](http://contacts.google.com). If you want to, you can just bookmark Google Contacts and configure your browser to show the bookmarks bar so you can access it easily.

Comment: It also means that contacts has become an independent app in it's own right, instead of being a Gmail feature. There are implementation biances between GSuite contacts and consumer account contacts but the apps look largely the same.

Comment: Something terrible is that when we click `Send email` from Contacts app it opens a pop-up window instead of just opening inline...

Answer (score 2):

The *keyboard shortcuts* with the old and new Gmail are the same, so if you have keyboard shortcuts enabled (Settings > General > Keyboard shortcuts) you can simply hit <kbd>g</kbd> then <kbd>c</kbd> to access your contacts. (<kbd>g</kbd> then <kbd>i</kbd> to go back to your Inbox.)

Answer (score 0):

For now, it's possible to simply go to the hash **#contacts** (https://mail.google.com/mail/#contacts) and it will load the old contacts manager integrated in Gmail.

Here's a simple [bookmarklet](/questions/tagged/bookmarklet) to speed the things up:

```
javascript: (function() { location.hash = '#contacts'; })();
```

And here a userscript that adds a button to the top:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Gmail Contacts button
// @description  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/119794/22453
// @namespace    gmail_
// @version      0.1
// @match        https://mail.google.com/mail/*
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    var it = setInterval(function(){
        if( $('div[role=banner]').length > 0 ) {
            clearInterval(it);
            $('div[role=banner]').find('div[id=gbwa]').parent().prepend('<button id="contactsDamit" value="yes" style="border:0;border-radius:3px;margin-left:2em;background-color: lightblue;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;color: darkslateblue;outline:0">contacts</button>');
            $('#contactsDamit').click(function(){
                if( $(this).val() === 'yes' ){
                    $(this).val('no').text('inbox');
                    location.hash = '#contacts';
                } else {
                    $(this).val('yes').text('contacts');
                    location.hash = '#inbox';
                }
            });
        }
    },1000);
})();
```